# Angular dialog closing immediately the first time, when using a bootstrap dropdown in the template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a dialog when a user clicks a button. I've found that when I add a bootstrap dropdown to the the dialog template then the first click (from the 'Open Dialog' button) returns immediately. If you click the 'Open Dialog' button a second (third, fourth,...) time then everything works as expected.

Is there some initialization code I'm missing?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.3.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="container">
    <button ng-click="showDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
  </div>


  </body>    
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function DialogController($scope, $dialog){
  $scope.items = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3","Item4"];

  $scope.close = function(){
    $dialog.close();
  };
} 

function MyController($scope, $dialog) {

  $scope.showDialog = function() {

      opts = {
        backdrop: true,
        backdropClick: true,
        template: '<div class="modal-body">' +
         '<div class="dropdown">' +
                '<a class="dropdown-toggle btn">'+
                'MyDropdown <span class="caret"></span>'+
                '</a>'+
                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'+
                '<li ng-repeat="choice in items">'+
                '<a>{{choice}}</a>'+
                '</li>'+
                '</ul>'+
                '</div>' +
         '</div>',
        controller: DialogController
      };        
      var d = $dialog.dialog(opts);
      d.open().then(function(result){
        console.log('dialog closed');
      });        
  };

}
```

**style.css**

```
.modal-body {
  height:200px;
}
```

Here is a plunker illustrating the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lJy5l6vlLycP4VlSiObE?p=preview

Comment: There is something in the dialog template that is not allowing rendering on the first click. [Here's a fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/AM56K7YWiBfI4H325his?p=preview) with a simplified template that works the first time.  It could be the ng-repeat, could be the `<a>` tags.  I couldn't troubleshoot because plunker kept caching old pages...

Comment: It's the attribute `class="dropdown-toggle btn"` - not sure where this is, but maybe the order of the loading of the stylesheets is causing it? Take out that attribute and it pops up the first time as expected, but your dialog ui is then broken ;).

Comment: Your plunker seems to be broken... can you check it again...